# Is there any markdown editor for linux supporting kotlin codeblocks highlighting?

Tags: text-editor, markdown, highlighting

I'm trying to create a kotlin tutorial in markdown, but I have not found of any editor supporting 
```` ```kotlin ```` codeblocks.

Is there any editor currently supporting (by default or with a plugin) syntax highlighting for kotlin inside markdown codeblocks?

Please validate that highlighting works, before providing any recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version (`2019.3`) of [IntelliJ IDEA Community](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux) supports it without additional plugins:

[image: idea screenshot]

**UPDATE:**

After [this fix](https://github.com/fwcd/kotlin-language-server/commit/3a4c0640c6f8462ee4e5eb49fc431e480408a4f0) the [fwcd Kotlin plugin](https://github.com/fwcd/vscode-kotlin-ide) for [vs-code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) now also supports kotlin codeblocks:

[image]